# How to use a custom action in Rails' controller, called by a nested route

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to add a custom action named "campaign" acting in a similar fashion like REST's "new" in the same controller, but it's purpose is different, so I wanted to separate them. Because, this campaign form will have some additional fields. One other alternative would be a passing an extra parameter to "new" action and render different templates for regular "new" action and custom "campaign". But, I wanna figure out why it didn't work out.

So, I come up with the following route ("messages" is the controller having both "new" and "campaign" actions):

```
get 'users/:user_id/messages/campaign', as: :campaign_user_message
```

or

```
resources :users do
   resources: messages do
      member do
        get 'campaign'
      end
   end
end
```

At the console output, I'm getting ActiverRecord:RecordNotFound since it does this:

```
Started GET "/users/1/messages/campaign" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-22 00:14:38 -0800
Processing by MessagesController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"user_id"=>"1", "id"=>"campaign"}
```

I'm calling the action in this way:

```
link_to campaign_user_message_path(@user)
```

Comment: Because it's taking the campaign as your message Id. You'd need at adjust your routes or include a message Id. Having said that, nesting this deeply is advised against in the rails docs. Can you shorten? Eg. /users/1/campaign

Comment: @simonmorley I have two-level routing so it should be fine with rails. Campaign is just a action in the second level not another controller. I'm looking a way to make this work: GET "/users/1/messages/campaign"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to have route such as "/users/1/messages/campaign" you should write smth like that:

```
resources :users do
 resources :messages do
    collection do
      get 'campaign'
    end
 end
end
```

If you write in your way(with member do ... end) you code will generate url "/users/:user_id/messages/:id/campaign". and you should pass @user and @message:

```
link_to campaign_user_message_path(@user, @message)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've did something like this overcome to the mentioned issue:

```
resources :users do
    get 'messages/new_campaign' => 'messages#new_campaign'
    post 'messages/create_campaign' => 'messages#create_campaign'
end
```

So, I can use the url helper "user_messages_new_campaign" to GET the action /users/:user_id/messages/new_campaign"